Adiabatic processes and temperatures
Do adiabatic processes maintain temperatures? That is, can temperatures remain constant during adiabatic processes?

Constant temperature processes are isothermal.  Adiabatic processes require no heat transfer, so work done on these processes raises their temperature.

An example of an adiabatic process where there is no change in temperature between the initial and final equilibrium states is the Joule expansion involving an ideal gas. It is an irreversible adiabatic process. During the expansion temperature and pressure gradients exist.
See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion
Hope this helps.

The Joule expansion actually changes temperature of gas in both partitions, unless the expansion is an effusion (opening is smaller than a mean free path). In the Joule process, only the final temperature is the same as the initial temperature, but during the process, temperatures change. To get this isothermal at all stages, one has to expand through a really small opening or porous plug which does not allow the gas to do work (Joule-Thomson process).

@JánLalinský When I said no change in temperature I was of course referring to the change between the initial and final equilibrium states.  Note I did not say this is an isothermal process.

That is not obvious, your answer will be interpreted in context of the question.

@JánLalinský See edits

As @David White commented, adiabatic processes are just those which do not involve heat transfer. However, the intensive parameter T (temperature) is able to change if the rest of manipulables variables change. You can check this diagram and more basic information about adiabatic processes and thermodynamics in general at Heat and Thermodynamics from Zemansky and Dittman, 1997.


The existence of entropy and of the global absolute temperature scale, the so-called integrating factor of the reversibly communicated heat, depends on the  impossibility that an isothermal surfaces may tangentially touch any of the isentropic surfaces. This is proved in paragraph 3.51 in Arens:"An Axiomatic Basis for Classical Thermodynamics".
Unlike Caratheodory who bases his analysis on his rather obscure adiabatic inaccessibility axiom, Arens derives this mathematical results directly form Kelvin's axiom, see para 3.4. So no to your question if the processes are reversible, but as @Bob_D commented, in an irreversible process such the Joule expansion they may coincide; note too that an irreversible adiabatic process is not isentropic. (To avoid confusion some physicists call adiathermal an irreversible adiabatic process and reserve the term adiabatic to mean reversible and therefore isentropic...) Here is a related question.
